# Having trouble, c#, webview and invokescriptasync. Can't perform Click() on Next link

Tags: javascript, c#, xpath, webview

So I'm parsing data from a web page. I have it so I can auto login to the site. However, I need to be able to click the "Next" Button on the page. 
However, the Next link doesn't have an ID assigned to it so the only way I can get the correct link is using Xpath. 
The code below works fine for filling the fields.

```
string functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('username').value = '{0}';", "usernamehere");
var result = string.Empty;
result = await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

However. this is the xpath I need to find the "Next" button.

```
"//a[contains(text(),'Next »')]"
```

I wanted to perform `.Click()` on the end but I can't get any of it to work.
I thought something like this, but it produces and Hresult error so there must be something wrong with the syntax?

```
String functionString = String.Format("document.evaluate(\"//a[contains(text(),'Next »')].Click();\"");
result = await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

HTML code from the page

```
<span>
<a ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pages_pagination.length-1}" href="" ng-click="nextPage(currentSearch)">Next »</a>
</span>
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Can you please share the html of the element.

Comment: I added the HTML to the original post

Comment: Give a try with `String functionString = String.Format("document.evaluate(\"//a[starts-with(text(),'Next')]\")].Click();\"");`

Comment: No change. Still produces this error:
System.Exception: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101'

Comment: `String functionString = String.Format("document.evaluate(\"//a[starts-with(text(),'Next')]\", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).click();")` I missed the part that you need additional param when trying to get element with xpath.

Comment: Added the solution as answer. Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left hand side in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below. You have to pass the reset of the params when using eval.

```
String functionString = String.Format("document.evaluate(\"//a[starts-with(text(),'Next')]\", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotItem(0).click();")
```